# How to lookup value higher in data.frame in R

Tags: r

I have a time series data.frame where all values are below each other. But on every date there are more cases that come back regulary. Based on the time series I am adding a column with some calculations. These calculations are done case-specific. But for these calculations I need the value of the previous date of that case. I have now idea about which function to use. Can anybody point me to a function or an example somewhere on the net? Thanks!!

To be clear, this is what I mean. On date 1 the old value (before the score) for case 'a' is 1200. Based on the score of 1 the new value becomes 1250. On date 2 the I want this new value 1250 for placed in the column 'old value' (and than do some calculations to come to the new value, that new value has to be placed again in de column old value on date 4 or so et cetera). For case B the same. So the new value after the score on date 1 is 1190 and has to be placed in the correct row on date 3 (on date 2 there is now case B) et cetera for 1000's of cases and dates.

```
date    name_case   score   old_value   new_value
1       a           1       1200        1250
1       b           2       1275        1190
1       c           1       1300        1310
2       a           3       1250    
2       c           1       1310    
3       B           1       1190
```

Comment: Can you try editing the question to clarify. It's not clear to me what the input data looks like and what the desired result should be. Why should the "new_value' of case 1 in row 1become 1250; and in row 2 be 1190?

Comment: That is not important for the question, it's just an example. But to clarify: before the event on date 1 the value of 'a' is 1200. Then the event scores '1' and the value is updated to 1250. That is just a calculation of the form y= ax+b (or something like that). My question is about how to get that 1250 from the new value of case a on date one into to the column 'old value' in date 2 for case a. Because, before the event on date 2 for case a, the value is 1250. The event is score=3 , so I'll do the calculation y=ax+b again to calculate the new value for case a after the event.

Comment: It's sounding like (although this is still not well explained) that you ought to save the original calculations as a `data.frame`, say `df_old` and then perform some type of `join` or `merge` to do the lookup plus calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do it. Assuming that we start with:

```
> dat
  date name_case score old_value new_value
1    1         a     1      1200      1250
2    1         b     2      1275      1190
3    1         c     1      1300      1310
4    2         a     3        NA        NA
5    2         c     1        NA        NA
6    3         b     1        NA        NA   # note ... fixed cap issue
```

And then make a subset with values for new_value:

```
dat1 <- dat[ !is.na(dat$old_value), ]
```

And then replace the NA old_values with results from `new_values` in the subset by `match`-ing on `name_case`

```
dat[ is.na(dat$old_value) , "old_value" ] <- 
          dat1$new_value[  match(dat[ !is.na(dat$old_value) ,"name_case" ], 
                                 dat1$name_case)]
```

`match` generates a numeric vector that is used to index the `new_values`.

```
> dat
  date name_case score old_value new_value
1    1         a     1      1200      1250
2    1         b     2      1275      1190
3    1         c     1      1300      1310
4    2         a     3      1250        NA
5    2         c     1      1190        NA
6    3         B     1      1310        NA
```